# What can cause purple rendering for nearby objects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I have no prior experience in unity and I'm building a VR application for android (google cardboard). I collaborate on the project with a few people and I have been responsible for making it possible to walk around in the scene in VR. I did this with some simple c# code I found in a tutorial. The problem that I have is that after building it for android and running it on several phones, the whole scene renders in purple. I tried converting to lightweight render pipeline but this led to nearby objects having the same issue in unity itself where there first were no problems in the editor. They render fine from a distance but within a certain distance, all the trees turn purple. Also, my console is full of errors on conflicting assets which is probably due to different versions of unity used by the rest of my group.

[image: This is a screenshot of my scene in unity]

Comment: Probably some missing material or shader is the cause of the issue. Have you tried to use their version of Unity so you don't get those conflicts? It's easy to install it using Unity Hub.

Comment: That color is correctly called "magenta" and is often used to indicate errors because it is so bright that there should be no valid use of it. (Reminds me that I want to get a "pinkest pink" t-shirt with a black checkerboard pattern so I look like a broken asset in real life).